How Did the the story of the Miracle of Hanukkah arise? 2 Macc. 10
In the NT, Jesus attended the feast of the Dedication (Hanukkah) in Jerusalem (John 10:22-23), and Jews have long marked the day by lighting candles for each of the days that the holy oil for the Temple menorah miraculously lasted.  Yet the scriptural account of event (accepted as an inspired text by Catholics) does not mention the miracle of the oil.

1 When Maccabeus and his companions, under the Lord’s leadership, had
recovered the temple and the city, 2 they destroyed the altars erected
by the foreigners in the marketplace and the sacred shrines. 3 After
purifying the temple, they made another altar. Then, with fire struck
from flint, they offered sacrifice for the first time in two years,
burned incense, and lighted lamps... 5 On the
anniversary of the day on which the temple had been profaned by the
foreigners, that is, the twenty-fifth of the same month Kislev, the
purification of the temple took place. 6 The Jews celebrated joyfully
for eight days as on the feast of Booths...7 Carrying rods entwined with
leaves, beautiful branches and palms, they sang hymns of grateful
praise to him who had successfully brought about the purification of
his own place. 8 By public decree and vote they prescribed that the
whole Jewish nation should celebrate these days every year.

Question: how did this account evolve into the tradition that God caused the holy oil (enough for one day only) to last for eight days?

I don't know enough to give a real answer, but in case it helps anyone else, two early records of the miracle are:
Megillat Ta'anit, Kislev 8, First century;
and Megillat Antiochus 69, Second century.

The boundary between legend and fact is often fuzzy.  This question would be better asked on Judaism SX.
